# How to detect circles from video feed in opencv?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to detect circles in video feeds from the webcam.I tried using Hough Circle Transform Function...but it gives me an error that "only 8-bit single channel images are allowed."

This was my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    _,frame=cap.read()

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(frame,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=0)
    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for i in circles[0,:]: 
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(hsv,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(hsv,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would like to get improvements to this code...
or any other methods by which I can detect circles.

Comment: Be more specific about what you tried and what problems arose.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to convert your input image to _grayscale_ using [`cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor).

Comment: Make sure to typecast the image data to a 8-bit digits if they're not already.

Comment: don't try to process things you don't understand. get some fundamental knowledge befor you dive into things like Hough transform. why don't you start with the first topic: what is a digital image? if you knew that you would understand what that error message means...

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=houghcircles#houghcircles) quite cleary states that input should be "8-bit, single-channel, grayscale input image", so why are you calling it with something else?

Answer (score 1):

You should use cvtColor() to transform your frame.